# New user has 2 issues: 1st it runs the 'new user config' every time and can't move icons on/off favorites

Tags: permissions, 22.04, useradd

I created a new user through Settings->User (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) on some (I have 6) new devices it seemed to work fine, on others it actually has 3 problems:

1st it runs the 'new user config' every time (each login asks for other accounts, send data, etc.)

2nd it can't move icons on/off favorites (I want to add Minecraft and remove non-end-user stuff)

3rd Starts Minecraft, but immediately 'cleans up' and exits. Others in this group of laptops work fine.

I've tried making that user Admin, no luck. I've tried chmod +x on the minecraft-launcher - no luck.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (recommended for Minecraft)

Comment: Please add any relevant information directly to your question: use "edit".